# Unable to access direct routes in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I just have deployed a VUEJS project to my Cpanel and have configured it with a subdomain as

```
https://web-dev.mydomain.xyz
```

it is working fine when I try to access through the exact domain name like

```
https://web-dev.mydomain.xyz
```

But when I try to directly access some routes like

```
https://web-dev.mydomain.xyz/posts?page_1
```

Then its returns page not found an error. So that I cannot share a specific page with anyone.

What I am doing wrong?
if the issue is at the VUEJS side or this is due to some misconfiguration of the project at the deployment server?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. Your server needs to be configured to serve the application at that route.

Please read [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) documentation for more information.